# Timer Not Functioning in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer, textbox

When i run this code it displays the Date and time in two separate textbox but the timer doesn't run.I mean the seconds part not moving...Here is my code Thanks

```
    Private Sub Studentattend_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = TimeString
    TextBox2.Text = DateString
    Label4.Text = Now
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label4.Text = TimeString
    Label4.Text = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: You have the timer set to update a label (twice) not textboxes (if you are expecting them to change).

Comment: What is the interval set to on the timer?

Comment: And, do you have Timer1.AutoReset set to True?

Comment: @Markus This is clearly a WinForms timer.

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you..If i use label it worked,it move in seconds but when inside the textbox doesn't work...Is it possible to work it out?

Comment: Put "Option Strict On" in your code files.  `Now` is a Date and not a string, so you should be doing the conversion.  It seems like you expect the variable TimeString to magically update itself.  It won't.  You have to update it in the tick event.  It's not clear why you can make it work for the Label and not the TexBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label4.Text = TimeString
    Label4.Text = Now
End Sub
```

There's no point to change Label4.Text twice, just use Now.ToString() to format the time. 
For example, Label4.Text = Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss") will give you the current time in hh:mm:ss format. Also, make sure that the timer interval (measured in milliseconds) is correct. And if you want to update your textbox, you will have to add the code inside the Timer1_Tick:

```
TextBox1.Text = Now.ToString()
```